# Redirect only a folder but not sublinks

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem about redirecting a web folder via .htaccess.

i have a folder, domain like `example.com/abc` and i can redirect this link to `example.com/aaa` link. But there are HTML files in abc directory, like `example.com/abc/1.html` and when i redirect the abc folder to aaa link, it redirects those HTML addresses too, like `example.com/aaa/1.html`.

I want to:

Redirect `example.com/aaa` (folder) to `example.com/abc` (webpage)

I dont want to:

Redirect `example.com/aaa/1.html` to `example.com/abc/1.html`

Is it possible to redirect only the folder address but not the sublinks?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this, for now I didn't tried it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} aaa/$
RewriteRule ^ abc [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the folder , you can use :

```
RedirectMatch ^/folder/?$ /abc/
```

The important part of the code here is **$** which means "end of the uri string" so this matches your /folder/ only not files and subfolders.

Answer (score -1):

Try
`DirectoryIndex abc/1.html`

This best article for create pretty URLs:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

hope it useful to you!